# A Puzzle That Marches Swiftly To The Median

Tags: rhyme, chess, steganography

James Bond enters M's office.

```
 BOND: I came as quickly as I could, sir. What's the emergency?  

 M:    It's those fiendish SMERSH agents again. They've stolen my chess pieces.  

 BOND: They've stolen *what* now?  

 M:    And they've hidden them in this poem!  

 BOND: With all due respect, sir, when was your last mandatory drug test?  

 M:    I have an extremely important match coming up. You must find them!
       If you are successful, you can have this bonus cheque.

 BOND: That's the most ludicrous... you know, I'm rather intrigued by 
       all the zeros on this cheque. May I see the poem?
```

Obviously, a man like Bond is too busy to do his own crypto-acrosto-steganography so he is counting on you to unravel this mystery. The words "pawn", "rook", "knight", "bishop", "queen", and "king" are hidden in this poem, disguised in a variety of ways (along with one other chess-related word as a bonus). Find them before M comes to his senses and cancels the offer.

> Go tear the fourth rotation's bane
>   Right on our knees we fall, insane.
>   He skids in oil, ignites the street
>   With fierce, oblique encircling heat.
>   Go now. I keep my land, my own
>   To mists and tempests ever prone

Comment: Great puzzle, still haven't figured it out entirely but I love it.

Comment: Done! I see that @Vincent Advocaat was on the same track :)

Comment: Ye, @Wu33o I needed your answer for king though, and i haven't figured out knight, i thought it might be something with Right on our knees if you put ight on kn you'd get knight, so if right were to fall on knees or something? i dunno, it's a bit weak :P and we also have rook from that sentence so probably not

Comment: @Vincent Advocaat Yeah I'm also not quite sure yet, still looking for a better option...

Comment: @Wu33o but i think you're on the right track, that knight should come from the 3th sentence.

Comment: I think I figured out where knight is. 3rd sentence, all words but first, second letter of each. (feel free to add to both answers)

Comment: @Dennis Meng Haha I just added it

Comment: Yeah, you almost certainly got it before I did; my comment looks like it squeaked in before your edit, but there's no way that edit took only 10 seconds or whatever the time difference was.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the answer is:

Pawn:

> When you use a rot -4 (or rot 22) on 'tear', you get the word 'pawn'

Rook:

> The first letters of the first four words on the second row spell 'Rook': (**R**ight **o**n **o**ur **k**nees)

Knight:

> The second letter of the words in the second sentence (except from the first one) form 'knight':
>  s**k**ids i**n** o**i**l, i**g**nites t**h**e s**t**reet

Bishop:

> The first letters of the last words of each sentence form the word 'bishop':
>  (**b**ane, **i**nsane, **s**treet, **h**eat, **o**wn, **p**rone)

Queen:

> obli**que** **en**circling

King:

> The first letters of the words in the fifth row form 'Gnik', which is 'king' inverted: (**G**o **n**ow. **I** **k**eep)

Hidden word:

> You can find the word 'mate' when you take the first letters of the second to fifth words in the last row: (**m**ists **a**nd **t**empests **e**ver)

Title:

> The puzzle is 'chess themed' (mar**ches** **s**wiftly to **the** **med**ian)

Comment: Nice, that knight makes sense, well done with the mystery word as well.

Comment: Well done. Make me happy and explain the title as well. ;-)

Comment: @HughMeyers Ah I should've seen that haha. I was focusing too much on the 'Median' part -.-

Answer (score 4):

Pawn can be found in:

> "Go **tear** the fourth rotation's bane", if you rot-4 the word pawn you get tear (and vice versa tear becomes pawn).

Rook can be found in:

> **R**ight **o**n **o**ur **k**nees we fall, insane.

EDIT: See **Wu33o**'s answer for the Knight.

Bishop can be found in:

> The first letter of the last word in every sentance: **b**ane, **i**nsane, **s**treet, **h**eat, **o**wn, **p**rone

The queen can be found in:

> With fierce, obli**que en**crypted heat.

The king can be found in: thanks to **Wu33o** for this answer, I couldn't figure it out.

> "**G**o **n**ow. **I** **k**eep my land, my own" it is inverted (gnik - king)